# Webpack wont bundle my .css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webpack

Here are my files;

webpack.config.dev.js:

```js
import path from "path";

export default {
 //entry point of our application
 entry: "./src/index",

 //Generates a sourcemap
 devtool: "inline-source-map",
 /*debug: true,*/  //This property was removed in Webpack 2

 devServer: {
  //Setting to false will display a list of all files that are being bundled
  noInfo:false
 },

 //Used to targert an environment, set to web in this app so that it can run in browser
 target: "web",

 //Specifies where to create the webpack bundle
    //With this configuration, webpack will not generate any physical file
    //It will create the bundle in memory and serve it to the browser
    //Need to define the path and name to simulate the files existence
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/src"),
  publicPath: "/",
  filename: "bundle.js"
 },

 //Enables webpack to process more than just JavaScript files
 module:{
  //In regards to migrating from webpack 1 to webpack 2
  //'module.loaders' is now 'module.rules'
  //'rules' tell webpack how to handle each file specified below
  rules: [
   {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
   {test: /\.css$/, use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader"
    /*{loader: "style-loader"},
    {loader: "css-loader", options: {modules: true}}*/
   ]}
  ]
 }
}
```

style.css:

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

table th{
 padding: 5px;
}
```

index.js:

```js
import "style.css";
```

my npm script used to run webpack:

> "start": "npm-run-all --parallel security-check dev-webserv lint:watch",

And I have each npm package properly installed as a dev-dependency, yet when i run the start script i get something along the lines of:

> ERROR in ./src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style.css' in 
>   'C:\Users\X\Projects\Node.js\JavaScript-dev-env\src'
>
> @ ./src/index.js 3:0-20
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

I was able to fix this problem before by uninstalling each dependency and reinstalling them but sadly that is not working this time. please help. i've gone through so many forums on here and other sites but nothing helps.

**Edit:

```js
import style from "style.css";
style.use();
style.unuse();
```

Modified index.js to try what user 'Neha Tawar' suggested and the result was

> (+) No known vulnerabilities found 
>   i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
>    × ｢wdm｣: Hash: 2b6ab568fd0c4866fe49 
>   Version: webpack 3.11.0
>    Time: 435ms
>   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names 
>   bundle.js  94.9 kB       0  [emitted]  main   [0] ./src/index.js 715 bytes {0} [built]
>   [1] ./node_modules/numeral/numeral.js 33.6 kB {0}
>   [built]
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'style.css' in 'C:\Users\X\Projects\Node.js\JavaScript-dev-env\src' @ ./src/index.js 3:13-33 i
>   ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

issue still persists, any more input towards this problem would be helpful, thanks

Edit: finally figured it out
Reason is due to the statement : import 'style.css';
It should be import './style.css';

Thanks for the help, though

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather d.ts for the css file has created or not.I think 
typescript is unable to load the css files or is unable to find the declarations for the same please do try these webpack.config.js changes of adding a **style-loader in plugins** might help and your related problem will be solved.

Please also check the link
[article for css typings creation and use](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10)

----EDIT-----
You are already using the plugin means you did added the style-loader. I think styles are not added on import/require(), but instead on call to use/ref. Styles are removed from page if unuse/unref is called exactly as often as use/ref.

```
import style from './file.css'

style.use(); // = style.ref();
style.unuse(); // = style.unref();
```

Check the link for explanation  [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader)

Comment: Hi there, didnt mention this above but here it is: I am not using typescript, i am using ES6 and transpiling it down to ES5, also the generated bundle is virtual (in memory) and hence does not generate a physical file, not sure what you mean by adding style-loader in the plugins, can you clarify?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the input and i have tried your suggestion but it still doesnt work, any other tips?